# How to return one or more items from a list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, random

Currently my code returns the name of the client and a random value from `visit_length`. I would like it to return the client name and then one or more of the elements from `visit_length`, i.e., `("Client 1", 15, 45), ("Client 2", 45, 60), ("Client 3", 30)`

```
N = 20      
randomitems = []
visit_length = [15, 30, 45, 60]
value_range = np.arange(0, N, 1)

for i in value_range:
    visits = ("Client %d" % i, random.choice(visit_length))
    randomitems.append(visits)
```

Any suggestions? I thought there might be something in the random library but I haven't found anything yet.

Thank you!

Comment: If `N` is 20, you don't have enough unique values from `visit_length`

Comment: Seems like what you want to do is generate another random number, that determines how many choices you want to append to item.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select a random number `k` of items to append with [`random.randint`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randint) and then take that number of elements from `visit_length` with [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample).

```
import random
import numpy as np

N = 20
randomitems = []
visit_length = [15, 30, 45, 60]
value_range = np.arange(0, N, 1)

for i in value_range:
    k = random.randint(1, len(visit_length))
    visits = ("Client %d" % i,) + tuple(sorted(random.sample(visit_length, k=k)))
    randomitems.append(visits)
```

If you want to allow for repeated items:

```
import random
import numpy as np

N = 20
MAX_VISIT_LENGTHS = 4  # You can choose as many as you want now I guess
randomitems = []
visit_length = [15, 30, 45, 60]
value_range = np.arange(0, N, 1)

for i in value_range:
    k = random.randint(1, MAX_VISIT_LENGTHS)
    vs = sorted(random.choice(visit_length) for _ in range(k))
    # If you do not want to sort use
    # vs = [random.choice(visit_length) for _ in range(k)]
    visits = ("Client %d" % i,) + tuple(vs)
    randomitems.append(visits)
```

Comment: What about if I wanted it to also have the option of returning the same value more than once? e.g. ("Client 1" 15, 15, 30, 15)

Comment: @plshelp I've updated the answer. Note that in that case you can choose any number of elements to append (the variable `MAX_VISIT_LENGTHS`).

Comment: Do the values have to be sorted in order? I would prefer it to be a mixed list.

Comment: @plshelp I thought you needed it to be sorted, but yeah it doesn't need to be. I've added a comment showing how.

Answer (score 1):

**updated answer** to return tuple

I might have misunderstood what you want but here is my take on the question:
We create a function that returns a random amount of items (between 1-4 = N) from the list x and returns them in random order.

```
import random

def visits_func():
    N = random.randint(1, 4)
    x = [15, 30, 45, 60]
    y = []
    while N:
        y.append(x.pop(random.randrange(len(x))))
        N -= 1
    return y

value_range = range(1,6) #1,2,3,4,5,6

randomitems = []

for i in value_range:
    visits = tuple(["Client %d" % i] + sorted(visits_func()))
    randomitems.append(visits)
```

prints, e.g.

```
[('Client 1', 15, 60),
 ('Client 2', 15),
 ('Client 3', 45, 60),
 ('Client 4', 30, 60),
 ('Client 5', 15, 30, 45)]
```

Comment: Good solution to append the *popped()* vlaue from x! upvote! I don't think you use `numpy` in this though so you could take out the import...

Comment: @JoeIddon Correct, numpy was used at some point but got removed. Updated answer.